# PowerShell Question: script to move my video files from separate folders on my hard drive to a central folder

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script to move my video files from separate folders on my hard drive to a central folder. The script looks like this:

```
#location of starting directory
$_sourcePath ="C:\Movies\ -recurse"
#location where files will be copied to 
$_destinationPath = "C:\New\"
#Array of extension that need to move from source path
$_FileType= @("*.*mp4")
```

When the scrip runs, nothing happens. I get no errors, but I also don't  get an of the *.mp4 files moved.
what is wrong with this script?

Comment: there is NOTHING in that code to move anything at all. [*grin*] take a look at `Get-Help *move*` & `Get-Help *item*` for some ideas.

Comment: There is alot to unpack here. There is alot missing and alot wrong. Basically in your script you only have created 3 variables and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$_sourcePath ="C:\Movies\"
$_destinationPath = "C:\New";

$_FileType= @("*.*mp4")

Get-ChildItem -recurse ($_sourcePath) -include ($_FileType) | move-Item -Destination ($_destinationPath)`
```

Comment: Please explain why this works. So the OP can learn what was wrong with his script

Comment: Line number 4 of script actually performs the moving of file (move-item) after it gathers all relevent file ( get-childitem). Recurse is used here for going deep down the subfolders if any.